# Improve reporting stored procedure execution time - tuning temporary tables?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been tasked with improving the performance (*and this is my first real-world performance tuning taks*) of a reporting stored procedure which is called by an SSRS front-end and the stored procedure currently takes about 30 seconds to run on the largest amount of data (based on filters set from the report frontend).

This stored procedure has a breakdown of 19 queries executing in it, most of which are transforming the data from an initial (legacy) format from inside the base tables into a meaningful dataset to be displayed to the business side.

I've created a query based on a few DMV's in order to find out which are the most resource-consuming queries from the stored procedure (small snippet below) and I have found one query which takes about 10 seconds, in average, to complete.

```
select
    object_name(st.objectid)                                                                    [Procedure Name]
    , dense_rank() over (partition by st.objectid order by qs.last_elapsed_time desc)           [rank-execution time]
    , dense_rank() over (partition by st.objectid order by qs.last_logical_reads desc)          [rank-logical reads]
    , dense_rank() over (partition by st.objectid order by qs.last_worker_time desc)            [rank-worker (CPU) time]
    , dense_rank() over (partition by st.objectid order by qs.last_logical_writes desc)         [rank-logical write]
        ...
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.sql_handle) as st
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (qs.plan_handle, qs.statement_start_offset, qs.statement_end_offset) as qp
where st.objectid in ( object_id('SuperDooperReportingProcedure') )
    , [rank-execution time]
    , [rank-logical reads]
    , [rank-worker (CPU) time]
    , [rank-logical write] desc
```

Now, this query is a bit strange in the sense that the execution plan shows that shows that the bulk of the work (~80%) is done when inserting the data into the local temporary table and not when interrogating the other tables from which the source data is taken and then manipulated. (screenshot below is from SQL Sentry Plan Explorer)

[image]

Also, in terms of row estimates, the execution plan has way off estimates for this, in the sense that there are only 4218 rows inserted into the local temporary table as opposed to the ~248k rows that the execution plan thinks its moving into the local temporary table. So, becasue of this, I'm thinking "statistics", but still do those even matter if ~80% of the work is the actual insert into the table?

One of my first recommendations was to re-write the entire process and the stored procedure so as to not include the moving and transforming of the data into the reporting stored procedure and to do the data transformation nightly into some persisted tables (real-time data is not required, only relevant data until end of previous day). But the business side does not want to invest time and resources into redesigning this and instead "suggests" I do performance tuning in the sense of finding where and what indexes I can add to speed this up.

I don't believe that adding indexes to base tables will improve the performance of the report since most of the time needed for running the query is saving the data into a temporary table (which from my knowledge it will hit tempdb, which means that they will be written to disk -> increased time due to I/O latency).

But, even so, as I've mentioned this is my first performance tuning task and I've tried to read as much as possible related to this in the last couple of days and these are my conclusions so far, but I'd like to ask for advice from a broader audience and hopefully get a few more insights and understanding on what I can do to improve this procedure.

As a few clear questions I'd appreciate if could be answered are:

- Is there anything incorrect in what I have said above (in my understanding of the db or my assumptions) ?
- Is it true that adding an index to a temporary table will actually increase the time of execution, since the table (and its associated index(es) is/are being rebuilt on each execution)?
- Could there anything else be done in this scenario without having to re-write the procedure / queries and only be done via indexes or other tuning methods? (I've read a few article headlines that you could also "tune tempdb", but I didn't get into the details of those, yet).

Any help is very much appreciated and if you need more details I'll be happy to post.

**Update (2 Aug 2016):**

The query in question is (partially) below. What is missing are a few more aggregate columns and their corresponding lines in the `GROUP BY` section:

```
select
    b.ProgramName
    ,b.Region
    ,case when b.AM IS null and b.ProgramName IS not null 
        then 'Unassigned' 
        else b.AM 
    end as AM
    ,rtrim(ltrim(b.Store)) Store
    ,trd.Store_ID
    ,b.appliesToPeriod
    ,isnull(trd.countLeadActual,0) as Actual
    ,isnull(sum(case when b.budgetType = 0 and b.budgetMonth between @start_date and @end_date then b.budgetValue else 0 end),0) as Budget
    ,isnull(sum(case when b.budgetType = 0 and b.budgetMonth between @start_date and @end_date and (trd.considerMe = -1 or b.StoreID < 0) then b.budgetValue else 0 end),0) as CleanBudget
    ... 
into #SalvesVsBudgets
from #StoresBudgets b
    left join #temp_report_data trd on trd.store_ID = b.StoreID and trd.newSourceID = b.ProgramID
where (b.StoreDivision is not null or (b.StoreDivision is null and b.ProgramName = 'NewProgram'))
    group by
        b.ProgramName
        ,b.Region
        ,case when b.AM IS null and b.ProgramName IS not null 
            then 'Unassigned' 
            else b.AM 
        end
    ,rtrim(ltrim(b.Store))
    ,trd.Store_ID
    ,b.appliesToPeriod
    ,isnull(trd.countLeadActual,0)
```

I'm not sure if this is actually helpful, but since @kcung requested it, I added the information.

Also, to answer some his questions:

- the temporary tables have no indexes on them
- RAM size: 32 GB

**Update (3 Aug 2016):**

I have tried @kcung's suggestions to move the `CASE` statements from the aggregate-generating query and unfortunately, overall, the procedure time has not improved, noticeably, as it still fluctuates in the range of ±0.25 to ±1.0 second (yes, both lower and higher time than the original version of the stored procedure - but I'm guessing this is due to variable workload on my machine).

The execution plan for the same query, but modified to remove the `CASE` conditions, leaving only the `SUM` aggregates, is now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any chance I can see the query ? and the indexes on both tables ?
How big is your ram ? how big is the row in each table(roughly) ?
Can you update statistics for both table and resend the query planner ?

To answer your question :

1. You're mostly right, except in the part of adding indexes. Adding indexes will help the query to do lookup. It will also give chance to the query planner to consider nested loop join plan instead of the hash join plan. Unfortunately, I can't answer more until my question being answered.
2. You shouldn't need to add index to the temp table. Adding index to this temp(or any insert destination table) table will increase write time, because the insert will need to update that index. Just imagine an index as copy of your table with less information and it sits on top of your table and it needs to be in sync with your table. Every write (insert, update, delete) needs to update this index.
3. Looking at both tables total rows, this query should run way faster than 10s, unless you have a lemon PC, then it's a different story.

**EDIT:**
Just want to point out for point 2, I didn't realise you're source table is temp table as well. Temporary table is destroyed after each session of a connection ended. Adding index to temporary table means that you will add extra time to create this index everytime you create this temporary table.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I'm using phone now. I'm just gonna be short.
So essentially 2 things :

- add primary key on temp table creation time so you do it in one go. Don't bother with adding nonclustered index or any covering index you will end up spending more time creating those.
- see your query, all of the case when statement, instead of doing it in this query, why don't you add them as another column in the table. Essentially you want to avoid calculation on the fly when doing group by. You can leave the sum() in the query as it's an aggregate query, but try and reduce run time calculation as much as possible.

Sample :

```
case when b.AM IS null and b.ProgramName IS not null 
    then 'Unassigned' 
    else b.AM 
end as AM
```

You can create a column named AM when creating table b.
Also those rtrim and ltrim. Please remove those and stick it in table creation time. :)

Comment: 1. Updated the questions with more details.

Comment: 2. No indexes on the temporary tables.

Comment: 4. Are you thinking about page fragmentation here?

Comment: 5. Statistics for temporary tables? I'm not sure it helps, since these estimates come from data that is from other temporary tables etc.

Comment: Ok, so RAM is not your issue. Have you try to add primary key on both tables at creation time ? You don't need to worry about statistics, this temp tables have limited life time and created each time, so the stats would be up to date.

Comment: Also one more thing, those calculation. Could you please do it in table creation time ? That way when the query is doing group by, it does less work. (all of the case whens)

Comment: Do calculations during table creation time? Can you be a little more explicit please? (edit your answer with how I'm supposed to change my query)

Comment: So, I have tested your suggestions and moved all of the CASE statements into the top, where I'm creating the **`"b"`** aliased table and unfortunately the time (per entire procedure) has not decreased. In my second query where I'm just pushing data into the `#SalesVBudgets` table I left only the aggegate operations (SUMs) and that did not change much (overall).

Comment: Ok, so primary key didn't help you much. Could you please show me what's the ACTUAL query plan is ? So run your query with "Include Actual Execution Plan" option on, and paste it here. No need for details. I just want to see what the query is doing.

Comment: The image posted in my question is the actual execution plan, not the estimated.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but since you've modified the query, the query plan changes.

Comment: Oh, so you want the new plan. I'll post it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Temporary tables is basically tables that is created in tempdb. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're using spinning disk are you ? not ssd. Do you have access to the hardware ? I think the quickest (it would be ugly) way would be to stick another SSD on your PC(I'm just assuming you're on a PC), move tempdb to that ssd, and you should see lots of writes improvement to temp tables.

Comment: I don't have that information, now. And most likely that won't happen since I don't have access to the hardware anyway, or resources, or anything else. I'm here just to make magic through SQL :-)

Comment: So you're on a cloud huh ? RDS ? Sorry couldn't be much help. Your query is stuck on writing speed. You need to speed up the write some how, but you're already on the fastest route (in terms of sql)  :(

Comment: From what I know so far, it's a shared environment, but i don't know about storage. But, it was good to narrow it down and find where my limitation is at, or what to try next. Thank you for your help so far! (and if any other ideas pop into mind, please please, drop a comment :-). I will do so if I find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding indexes to the temporary table will definitely improve the read call but slows down the write calls to the temporary table.
2. Here, as you mentioned, there are 19 queries executing in the procedure, so analyzing only one query with execution plan would not be more helpful.
3. Adding more, if possible, execute this query only & check how much time it takes (rows affected).
4. Other approach you may try, not sure if possible in your case, try using table variable instead of temporary table. This is because, using table variable over the temporary table has additional advantages such as, procedure is pre-compiled, no transactional logs are maintained. & more, you don't need to write drop table.

Comment: 2. Most of the queries are `SELECT` from one temp table into another (`SELECT INTO FROM`), with a few modifications of the data based on a few more joins / aggregates etc. And there are a few more queries that sum up to about 15 more seconds (but those are 4-5 queries, not 1). So, I'm trying to shave off as much time as possible from this one large query before moving to the others, which I don't think they can be improved (yet).

Comment: 3. I don't think I can get more detailed information about these queries from another place other than the DMV's. So, adding / testing more queries at a time won't help me find anything new as I already know how much time it takes and who are my "culprits".

Comment: 4. I have tried table variables and the execution time has improved, but only by 5-10% (0.25 - 1 sec) after about 25 repeated executions, on average it's about 0.5 seconds. And I can "blame" this range on the "server" load. Also, from what I know, table variables will still hit tempdb if they don't fit in memory, so I/O latency added again. I agree about the transaction log, but that's not my concern now and not something the business wants to hear (if it can't **solve the problem**). Also, drop table isn't explicitly stated, the temp tables get destroyed on session close.

Comment: Since he is referencing temp table in the select for other temp tables, I would imagine adding indexes on such temp table could speed things up considerably if the tables were large enough. We have done this many times for large complex processes and it is the easiest thing to try first as it doesn't involve rewriting queries and then testing to make sure you didn't change the functionality in the course of speeding things up. Usually we insert to the temp table, create the index, do the other work and then drop the indexes at the end.

Comment: Table variables are generally faster for small data sets and indexed temp tables are generally better for large ones.

Answer (score 0):

1. One suggestion is to increase the execution time of stored procedure.
   `cmd.CommandTimeout = 200 // in seconds.`
2. You can also generate a report link and email it to user when the report was generated.
3. Other than that use CTE never use temp tables as they are more expensive.